# how to remove serverSignature from Wordpress installation

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to remove server Signature from Wordpress blog. I am using this setting for .htaccess:

```
ServerSignature Off
```

but I see X-Powered-By has gone and not this ServerSignature:

*Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.30*

I am setting the value in root public folder of .htaccess file.

Comment: ok. So this means that for my Apache version, I cannot control the serverSignature as it is controlled by ServerToken and that can be set for all at a time and not for each virtualHost. Thanks

Comment: You can set all at once only if you can edit the httpd.conf of the server. If not - you can make a .htaccess for every virtualhost.

Answer (score 0):

[Better late than never LOL]

According to various sources, the inability to remove certain headers is design issue of Apache e.g. [Removing http headers in Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464184/removing-http-headers-in-apache2)

The best idea through Apache alone (as far as I'm aware) is to suppress how much information is given by adding this to your httpd.conf or apache.conf files (not .htaccess):

```
ServerTokens Prod
```

So in the header it will show something like:

```
Server: Apache
```

instead of your full:

```
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.30
```