# Removing http headers in Apache2

Tags: apache, header, unset

On an Apache2.2.9 hosted site, I would like to remove the headers below.

Date Thu, 16 Dec 2010 17:49:45 GMT
Server Apache
Keep-Alive timeout=15, max=92
Connection Keep-Alive

Let me preempt the discussion on whether or not it it right/legal/nice to remvoe Server and Date: I have read the standard and I still want to do it. The bytes saved are significant (average response size is ~200B).

In my site.conf (last load from apache2.conf) I have tried this with no success:

```
    Header unset Date
    Header unset Server
    Header unset Connection 
    Header unset Keep-Alive
```

Other Header unset directives do work (so mod_headers is loaded).

Answer (score 5):

Have you noticed this [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40026)? The inability to unset certain headers is a design issue in Apache. The patch attached contains a way to remove the Server header. Looking at it briefly it seems that lobotomizing the rest of the unwanted default included headers can be done at modules/http/http_filters.c, around line 1000...

Comment: Interesting answer .. do you have a patch for that? Around line 1000 it says `form_header_field(&h, "Server", server);` what would be a patch that allows me just to unset all headers?