# Rewrite HTTP server header with PHP

Tags: php, http-headers

When I try to use this code:

```
header('X-Powered-By: ASP.NET');
header('Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5');
```

the headers that have sent are:

```
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: If you aren't getting an error saying the headers are sent you have to adjust your apache config http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens and to get rid of X-Powered-By uncomment or add the `expose_php = off` to your php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Your Server header is being replaced by apache2.

The solution may be to completly disable sending Server header by web server. In fact apache (and most of web servers) does not allow you to completly disable server signature.

You can find some useful information here: [Removing http headers in Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464184/removing-http-headers-in-apache2)