# How to get rid of "Server: Apache" from response header

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I wonder if there is any way to remove the whole "Server: Apache" from the response header? I am able to hide the server info but I need to remove it completely (I don't even want to change the Apache to other thing).

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have attached a photo for the desired output:

[image: Desired Header Output]

Answer (score 3):

The inability to unset header is reported as a bug [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40026)
Check [this](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40026#c4) entry in the report. Also after some researching I found something saying that Header can be unset by including a module. Read it here, second last entry
http://apache-http-server.18135.x6.nabble.com/header-unset-server-does-not-work-td5006287.html
Also this solution [Removing http headers in Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464184/removing-http-headers-in-apache2)

Comment: Did you read my question? Your solution wont hide the whole "Server: Apache"!

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried it out and restarted the server with no luck! Headers module is enabled.

Comment: @halfer You are mistaken. I didn't disrespect anybody here.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend and thanks for Vishnuraj for his great inputs